Слияние веток git merge
У меня есть файл с кодом
print("Hellow world")

Я сделал для него коммит в ветке master. Потом создал ветку feature. Поменял код в файле на
with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("Hello, world!")

Сделал коммит. Переключился на ветку master и сделал git merge feature.
Я планировал, чтобы в файле оказался код из обеих веток. Вот что выдал git:
 Updating 0fa9a7c..00b40ce
Fast-forward
 file.py | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

Но содержание файла не изменилось. Как сделать слияние, чтобы в одном файле было оба коммита?

Что значит оба коммита? 2 текста разных?

Да То есть плаируется в результате:

with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
f.write("Hello, world!")                                                                                                                                           print("Hellow world")

Так вам надо добавить оба текста , и будет у вас их 2, слияние веток, это замещение, а не добавление

Задание требует сделать именно так. 4. Создать проект «Hello world» с выводом сообщения в консоль. Выполнить
коммит. Приложить скриншот кода и коммита.
5. Создать другую ветку. Реализовать код «Hello world» с выводом
сообщения ТОЛЬКО в файл. Создать коммит. Приложить скриншот кода
и коммита.
6. Слить 2 ветки так, чтобы при выполнении кода сообщение выводилось в
консоль и в файл. Приложить скриншот кода и коммита.

Хорошо, когда вы сделали новую ветку, у вас был код в файле который там существовал до ее создания? Т.е. тот который был в ветке мастер?

Да, был. После создания ветки, перед добавлением в отслеживание файла и коммитом, я поменял содержимое файла

Вы должны добавить код в файл, а не менять его содержимое, т.е. вы не трогаете то что было там, а добавляете реализацию новую. Вы не правильно поняли смысл задания. И ещё раз, Слияние, это замещение одной ветки другой, с изменениями, а не добавление .

В ветке feature сделали 2 изменения - удалили строку из файла, добавили две новых. После слияния оба этих изменения применяются к файлу, остается две строки. Слияние не склеивает файлы, слияние склеивает изменения.

Как и обcуждали в комментариях выше, слияние это объединение изменений начиная с общего предка(base). Так же ветку куда сливаем назовем (ours), а откуда (theirs).
В итоге получаем, что (base) + (ours changes) + (theirs changes) -> merge
В вашем случаем происходим самый простой способ слияния (forward) перемоткой, т.е. он просто передвигает указать вперед и все. т.к. base = ours changes.
Если вы хотите реализовать это именно как вы понимаете, то надо сделать 2 ветки, где в каждом своя реализация.

Начало такое же как и у вас, пишем и коммитим.
Затем нужно вернуться к прошлому коммиту(есть несколько вариантов):

git checkout '@~'
or
git log --oneline --all
git checkout <копируете и вставляете код прошлого коммита>

' ' - нужны, если вы работаете на windows

Далее на нем создаете другую ветку и переключаемся на нее:

git checkout -b fix


Можете посмотреть, что там вообще и где вы:

git log --oneline --all


Теперь удаляете в файле, что было и меняете на то, что нужно в задании и делаете commit:

//делаете изменения в проекте
git add .
git commit -m 'комментарий'


Теперь в зависимость откуда куда вы хотите слить изменения вы переключаетесь либо на master или fix и сливаете ваши изменения.
Допустим нужно в master:

git switch master
git merge fix

если не будет конфликта, то все пройдет гладко, но т.к. у вас по сути модифицируется одно и тоже место, то он будет.

Затем зайдете в файл. там появятся спец. метки вы выбираете, что именно сохранить(метки удалить надо) и продолжаете слияние:

git add .
git merge --continue


Ну вот и все!

